# Show/Hide Editor is missing in the CMS > Pages

Tags: html, magento1.9.2.4, editor

Can anyone here help us to fix our issue on the

> CSM > pages

The **Show/Hide** Editor is missing

> https://www.screencast.com/t/DqD5QEiaDmNG

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

- Use the Firefox browser
- Update Adobe Flash Player version
- Restart Firefox browser
- Go to product images in admin
- Allow the flash player on browser (alert on the top left)

For use in Google Chrome enable website in setting - https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html

For Safari - https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-safari.html

Comment: Thank you @Altravsita but still doesn't work :(

Comment: any error in browser consol or magento log files?